# Form Control styling from React Bootstrap is not reflecting in timeInput of ReactDatePicker

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-datepicker

I am using ReactDatePicker with React Bootstrap. I have applied `form-control` className to make the DatePicker pick up the default stylings of bootstrap as shown in the code below.

```
     <DatePicker
            minDate={new Date()}
            selected={selectedTime}
            onChange={(date) => {
                setSelectedTime(date);
            }}
            formatWeekDay={day => day.slice(0, 3)}
            className='form-control'
            placeholderText="Select Date & Time"
            timeIntervals={1}
            dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm aa"
            showTimeInput
            fixedHeight
        />
```

However the time input component is having a transparent background as shown in the image below
[image]

The DatePicker is been used from within a Modal.

How can I fix this please?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding overflow:hidden css property in the modal

Comment: Can you provide a full example? I copied your code but I do not get the same CSS styling.